# The Constructor is Undefined

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, undefined

In my main class I have the following code :

```
Polynomial P = new Polynomial(polynomial);
```

In another class I have the following code :

```
public class Polynomial {

    private int[] polynomial;

    public Polynomial(int[] polynomial) {
        this.polynomial = polynomial;
    }
}
```

Why is the constuctor Polynomial(int[]) undefined?

by the way...polynomial in the main class points to :

```
int [] polynomial = new int[count];
```

This is the full main class :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "This is the Polynomial Cal" +
            "culator Menu. Please ente" +
                "r your menu selection:\n (1) Enter c" +
                    "oefficients of polynomial P(x). \n (2) Enter co" +
                    "efficients of polynomial Q(x). \n (3) Sum polynomi" +
                        "als P(x) and Q(x). \n (4) Multiply polynomials P(x) and Q(" +
                            "x). \n (5) Quit.", "Polynomial Menu",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    Scanner inputScanner =new Scanner(input);           //Scanner for Menu
    int userChoice = inputScanner.nextInt();            //Menu Choice
    if(userChoice>=1 && userChoice<=5)                  //User Input Catch
    {
        switch(userChoice)
        {
        case 1: String coefficientInput= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter th" +
                "e coefficients of the terms in the polynom" +
                    "ial.(Ax^n, Bx^(n-1)...Yx,Z) \n Only ent" +
                        "er the values of the coeffien" +
                            "ts i.e (A + B - C + D) ");
                Scanner countScanner = new Scanner(coefficientInput);       //Scanner for count
                int coefficient= countScanner.nextInt();
                int count=1;
                while(countScanner.hasNextInt())
                {
                    count++;
                    countScanner.nextInt();
                }
                int [] polynomial = new int[count];                         //Size of Array=Count
                Scanner coefficientScanner = new Scanner(coefficientInput);
                int term = 0;
                System.out.println(count);
                int i=0;
                while(coefficientScanner.hasNextInt())                                  //Initialisation of array
                {
                    term=coefficientScanner.nextInt();
                    polynomial[i]=term;
                    i++;
                }
                Polynomial P = new Polynomial(polynomial);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No option selected. Please try again.","Input Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}

}
```

The error occurs at Polynomial P =new Polynomial(polynomial)

Comment: This seems to be Java. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have mentioned that.Total noob here

Comment: @user1873789: whatever you posted seems correct.

Comment: Believe the compiler - it's wrong.

Comment: What you have so far seems to be correct.  Can you post more of your code and the actual exception you get?

Comment: check your code and compile it again. compile both classes. Constructor should be available.

Comment: OK uploaded full main...error still exists :/

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me. If you are using an IDE, try cleaning and rebuilding your workspace.

Comment: In your update you lost the code for the Polynomial class.  Where is it actually located?  This could be a private/public constructor issue

Comment: I just reuploaded the main class....The only thing that is in the Polynomial class  is the constructor

Answer (score 2):

I guessing that the reference named `polynomial` in the main class doesn't point to an `int []`.  If it's a reference of type `Polynomial` you'll either have to create another constructor that takes a `Polynomial` (aka "copy constructor") or change the type of `polynomial`.

I don't like the way you wrote that constructor.  It's not private that way; the reference you pass in is mutable.  Make a defensive copy.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
public class Polynomial {

    private int[] coefficients;

    public Polynomial(int[] coefficients) {
        if (coefficients == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("coefficients cannot be null");
        this.coefficients = new int[coefficients.length];
        System.arraycopy(0, coefficients, 0, this.coefficients, this.coefficients.length);
    }

    public Polynomial(Polynomial p) {
        this(p.coefficients);
    }
}
```

This is also a naive design.  No floating point coefficients?  And it's inefficient if you want to model something like `y = x^1000 + 1`.  You'll have two non-zero coefficients in a very big array.

A better design is to create a `Monomial` and have a `Polynomial` maintain a `List` of them.

Comment: Just edited there...polynomial does point to an array of ints

Answer (score 0):

The following code will compile happily, no problem with your class definition and constructor.

Take care how you define and initialize your integer array.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] polynomial = new int[]{2, 1, 2};
    Polynomial P = new Polynomial(polynomial);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.I just deleted one line of code and retyped it in-then it worked.What just happened??